# Passing result of one table to another table in Database?

Tags: mysql

I have the following scenario: I am trying to pass result of one query to another , In this case I am trying to pass view_id in another query since this are ids they are unique and cant be duplicate in any case .

```
select view_id from view where view_query_id = "18711987173" 

select queue_id from queue where queue_view = view_id
```

`

I saw some examples and I tried executing them something like as

```
select view_id from view where view_query_id = "18711987173 exists (select queue_id from queue where queue_view = view.view_id)
```

But surely this didnt helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common table expression

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT view_id FROM view WHERE view_query_id = "18711987173")
SELECT queue_id FROM queue q INNER JOIN temp t ON q.queue_id = t.view_id;
```

This should work regardless of what relationship is between those tables. You can replace the `JOIN` by `WHERE..IN`, but this way seems cleaner and takes care if the no. of values in `IN` becomes too large.

Answer (score 0):

Use table expression

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT view_id FROM view WHERE view_query_id = "18711987173")
SELECT queue_id FROM queue q INNER JOIN temp t ON q.queue_id = t.view_id;
```